# Numpy sum elements in array based on its value

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have unsorted array of indexes:

```
i = np.array([1,5,2,6,4,3,6,7,4,3,2])
```

I also have an array of values of the same length:

```
v = np.array([2,5,2,3,4,1,2,1,6,4,2])
```

I have array with zeros of desired values:

```
d = np.zeros(10)
```

Now I want to add to elements in d values of v based on it's index in i.

If I do it in plain python I would do it like this:

```
for index,value in enumerate(v):
    idx = i[index]
    d[idx] += v[index]
```

It is ugly and inefficient. How can I change it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) which is supposedly pretty efficient for such accumulative weighted counting, so here's one with that -

```
counts = np.bincount(i,v)
d[:counts.size] = counts
```

Alternatively, using `minlength` input argument and for a generic case when `d` could be any array and we want to add into it -

```
d += np.bincount(i,v,minlength=d.size).astype(d.dtype, copy=False)
```

**Runtime tests**

This section compares `np.add.at` based approach listed in the [`other post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33818168/3293881) with the `np.bincount` based one listed earlier in this post.

```
In [61]: def bincount_based(d,i,v):
    ...:     counts = np.bincount(i,v)
    ...:     d[:counts.size] = counts
    ...: 
    ...: def add_at_based(d,i,v):
    ...:     np.add.at(d, i, v)
    ...:     

In [62]: # Inputs (random numbers)
    ...: N = 10000
    ...: i = np.random.randint(0,1000,(N))
    ...: v = np.random.randint(0,1000,(N))
    ...: 
    ...: # Setup output arrays for two approaches
    ...: M = 12000
    ...: d1 = np.zeros(M)
    ...: d2 = np.zeros(M)
    ...: 

In [63]: bincount_based(d1,i,v) # Run approaches
    ...: add_at_based(d2,i,v)
    ...: 

In [64]: np.allclose(d1,d2)  # Verify outputs
Out[64]: True

In [67]: # Setup output arrays for two approaches again for timing
    ...: M = 12000
    ...: d1 = np.zeros(M)
    ...: d2 = np.zeros(M)
    ...: 

In [68]: %timeit add_at_based(d2,i,v)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.83 ms per loop

In [69]: %timeit bincount_based(d1,i,v)
10000 loops, best of 3: 52.7 µs per loop
```

Comment: It seems very efficient. Thank you. Your anwer is even better.

Comment: Can you show me an example with two dimensions. Where instead of "i' I have "x" and "y", and "d" is two-dimensional array?

Comment: @MihailKondratyev I would suggest posting that as a separate question as that's different from what you have in the question. Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

```
np.add.at(d, i, v)
```

You'd think `d[i] += v` would work, but if you try to do multiple additions to the same cell that way, one of them overrides the others. The [`ufunc.at`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) method avoids those problems.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like it works. Is there a way to do it in 2d? when my d is 2d array and instead of i I have x and y array?

Comment: @MihailKondratyev: `np.add.at(d, (x, y), v)`.

Comment: This version works nicely with values that are not Real numbers. The `np.bincount(_, weights)` variant will fail when `weights` has `dtype(complex)`.